# Generating function for parenthesized expressions

Tags: generating-functions, formal-languages, catalan-numbers

I am trying to solve this problem but I'm not getting a way to start with, can anybody assist me please

[image]

Comment: Google "Catalan numbers". (Joking. Well, almost.)

Comment: I agree with metamorphy; see [as well here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e3bf/8024709e7291640b6a040af256e17ddc7cc8.pdf).

Comment: @metamorphy I understand (I am on the same "wavelength"). Thank you for your prompt answer. I erase my question...

Comment: What we can say to the OP that the combinatorics of "well formed formulas" (WFF, a classical concept in formal languages) in the case of parenthesized formulas is exactly governed by Catalan numbers.